# Atom - ReactJS Components Compiling to JS instead of ES6

Tags: reactjs, github, atom-editor

I switched branches for my ReactJS project and Atom is showing in all of my components in pure JS:

**MyComponent (in pure JS):**

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

var _react = require('react');

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _propTypes = require('prop-types');

var _propTypes2 = _interopRequireDefault(_propTypes);

var _reactRedux = require('react-redux');

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var MyComponent = function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(MyComponent, _React$Component);

  function MyComponent() {
    _classCallCheck(this, MyComponent);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (MyComponent.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(MyComponent)).apply(this, arguments));
  }

  _createClass(MyComponent, [{
...
```

Usually, my component looks like this:

**MyComponent (ES6 – as I normally see it):**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
...
```

I attempted switching back to the branch I had just been working on, but the components there are in the same view/format as well.  I checked GitHub, and my project looks "normal" there.  I tried playing around with the "View" and "Package" settings of Atom, but no luck.

**Does anyone know why my project is compiling to pure JS rather than to ES6 and how to revert to compile as ES6?**

Comment: This "odd format" is javascript. It looks like your es6 was compiled to js

Comment: @imjared thanks, do you happen to know why this would suddenly be happening or how to get Atom to compile it as ES6?